# Spring Security multiple filterChainProxy mapping/filters, custom filters Json Output

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a part of my web application that is an RESTfull api and part a more standard web-pages.

I wish to have the REST part with some custom filters such as the EntryPoint, SuccessHandler and FailureHandler. This part is within the /rest/** mapping.

In the other hand, everything else needs to have more common filters and is mapped with /**.

The problem is to find an easy way to define the filterChainProxy with different mapping-filters.

Right now this solution doesn't work:

```
    <!-- Normal web app -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <form-login/>
    <logout/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
</http>

<!-- Configure RESTfull services -->
<http use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" >
    <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="restAuthenticationSuccessHandler" login-page="/rest/login" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-url="/rest/logout" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" method="GET" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" method="POST" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" method="PUT" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" method="DELETE" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
</http>
```

It complains with: the univseral match being before other patterns.

**Is there a way to define such a thing without resorting to define the filterChainProxy with the  definition?** The http version does help quite a lot to reduce the amount of configuration as I will have to manually set a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter etc.

The next problem is more simple: I have to respond, after the form-login authentication with a JSON object.

So far, I have implemented a SuccessHandler (actually a version of the SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler without the redirect part).

How do I write my JSON output?

I must have something like this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
```

with:

```
{"success":true,"customer {"email":"customer@email.com","session_id":"b83a41dfaca6785399f00837888886e646ff9088"}}
```

and a similar thing with the FailureHandler. It must be quite simple and it's surely is some very basic thing, but how do you do that? Redirecting to a custom controller is not a solution since I will have the 301 redirect status that a very simple REST client might not be able to understand.

At the very least, I wish to have only the http header and no body at all.

thanks!

Comment: What's the reason to place handlong of 2 driffrent interfaces (WWW and REST) in a single ApplicationContext? Do You have some context/session sharing between the two? Does loggin in to WWW means logging in to REST too? If so, then why separate login action? If no, then why to put them together? Couldn't those be separate apps providing diffrent interfaces for single underlying service layer?

Comment: It's like having a REST part inside a normal web app. I don't want another authentication process, I just want other filters. The REST part just has to show an error when there is no authentication, but in the other hand, on a web page I have to redirect the users to the login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can upgrade to Spring Security 3.1 it [supports multiple chains using namespace configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-http).

Comment: Thanks, updating to 3.1 does the trick! http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html#filter-chains-with-ns for more information. I had to use the pattern attribute inside the http namespace.